# The value of bl when calling int 10h

Tags: assembly, x86

I am trying to write a boot sector that prints a string to the screen. I am using nasm. My tutorial says that when calling int 10h you have put the value 07h into bl. This is the color of your text. I tried changing the value of bl to 08h but it did not print anything! So I tried changing it to 06h and still nothing! Is it possible to change the color using the value in bl?
If so what value matches what color?

If I change the value in ah will int 10h do something else (for example scan text into al)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to print a character, you need to put:

1. 9 in `AH` (write instruction)
2. The character in `AL`
3. The page number in `BH`
4. The colour attribute in `BL` (high 4 bits are background, low 4 bits are foreground)
5. The number of characters to write in `CX`
6. Call BIOS interrupt 10h

So:

```
mov ah, 9  ; Write instruction for int 0x10
mov al, 64 ; A
mov bh, 0  ; Page number
mov bl, 4  ; Red on black (00000100 - High 0000 is black, low 0100 is red)
mov cx, 1  ; Writes one character
int 10h
```

About you're last question, yes. Interrupt 10h is the BIOS video services. It has [many functions](http://www.computing.dcu.ie/~ray/teaching/CA296/notes/8086_bios_and_dos_interrupts.html), all controlled by the value of `AH`. Each one has different arguments.

Comment: I tried what you said and it prints "A", but in white on black not red on black.

Comment: On which hardware/VM are you testing this?

Comment: I just noticed what I was doing wrong. My tutorial  said to put 0Eh into ah. Now I tried 9 like you said and it works... I wonder why.

Comment: 0Eh is a different BIOS video services function (see the link in my answer). It also writes a character at the current cursor position, but with the current attributes. There's no argument for the colour attribute with 0Eh. If you want to change the colour attributes when printing a character, you need to use 09h instead.